# How to crop rectangle box in image in matlab code

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I want to crop a detected faces in my code. Here is my code.

```
function DisplayDetections(im, dets)

imshow(im);

k = size(dets,1);

hold on;
for i=1:k
   rectangle('Position', dets(i,:),'LineWidth',2,'EdgeColor', 'r'); 

end
imcrop(rectangle);
hold off;
```

Their is syntax error in cropping.
Can anybody help in cropping rectangle box detected in above box.

Comment: What's the syntax error?  This code should run.... unless you are pushing the Run button in your editor....

Comment: The syntax error is probably that you are assigning a function, 'rectangle' as in input argument to the function 'imcrop'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code only **draws** the rectangles in your image.  If you actually want to crop out portions of the image with the defined rectangles, use [`imcrop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html).

As such, you would do something like this to store all of your cropped rectangles.  This is assuming that `im` and `dets` are already defined in your code from your function:

```
k = size(dets,1);
cropped = cell(1,k);

for i=1:k
   cropped{k} = imcrop(im, dets(i,:));
end
```

`cropped` would be a cell array where each element will store a cropped image defined by each rectangle within your `dets` array.  This is assuming that `dets` is a 2D array where there are 4 columns, and the number of rows determines how many rectangles you have.  Each row of `dets` should be structured like:

```
[xmin ymin width height]
```

`xmin`, `ymin` are the horizontal and vertical co-ordinate of the top-left corner of the rectangle, and `width` and `height` are the width and height of the rectangle.

If you want to access a cropped portion in the cell array, simply do:

```
crp = cropped{k};
```

`k` would be the k<sup>th</sup> rectangle detected in your image.